# Creating an interval with a loop and determining minimum and maximum values without arrays in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, max, min

I have been given this assignment for homework:

Write a program that prompts the user to enter two positive integer numbers: top and bottom of an interval and create two functions to display the largest and the smallest number in that interval that is divisible by 2 and is not divisible by 4 Display the result of calling both functions.

Sample run:

```
Enter the bottom of the interval: 100
Enter the top of the interval: 2200
Output: Minimum: 102
Output: Maximum: 2198
```

--
I get to here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int bottom,top;
    int x;
    int pl = 0;

    cout << "Enter the bottom of the interval:";
    cin >> bottom;
    cout << "Enter the top of the interval:";
    cin >> top;

    for( x = bottom+1; x < top; x ++)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0 & x % 4 != 0)


    }


    return 0;
}
```

and can't quite figure out how to print the maximum and minimum values. Could you throw me a hint?

Comment: Write two functions.  The firs finds the min starting from the bottom of the range, returns that, and then you print it.  The second function starts at the top of he range and works down until it finds the max, returns it, and then you print that.

Comment: Here's a hint: the loop you showed starts with the lowest number from the range, and works it way up. Therefore, the first number it finds will be the lowest number that meets the criteria. Congratulations! You now solved half of the problem. Now, think hard: what would be the equivalent approach for the highest number? Should be ridiculously obvious. Having done that, your only remaining task is to check for a pathological example where the range is too small, i.e. minimum=15, maximum=16.

Comment: you dont even need the loops if you consider that `biggest = maximum - (maximum%4)` gives you the next biggest number (starting from maximum) that is divisible by 4. I leave it for you the get the full expressions ;)

Comment: But as soon as I write the cout << x; it gives me all the values in the range.

Comment: @Illusive: I have added some explanation to my answer. Do check it out if you have any doubt regarding my method of finding `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 1):

This code fragment achieves the requirement:

```
min = bottom + (bottom%2)
if (min%4 == 0)
    min = min + 2
max = top - (2 - top%2)
if (max%4 == 0)
    max = max - 2
```

We find the `min`, by firstly calculating the minimum number `>=` `bottom` that is divisible by `2`. If `bottom` is divisible by `2`, then `min` = `bottom`, otherwise we add the `remainder`, i.e. `bottom%2`, to `min`.

Next, check whether `min` is divisible by `4` or not. If not, then we don't need to change the `min`, otherwise we add `2` to `min` because in that case, `min` won't be divisible by `4` while it will still be divisible by `2`. This `min` would be the least possible number satisfying the constraints in your question.

Same applies for finding the `max`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Thank you for helping me out!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int bottom,top;
int x;



cout << "Enter the bottom of the interval:";
cin >> bottom;
cout << "Enter the top of the interval:";
cin >> top;


int mini = bottom + (bottom%2);

if(mini%4 == 0)
    mini = mini + 2;

int high = top - (2 - top%2);

if(high%4 == 0)
    high = high - 2;

    cout << "Maximum:" << high << endl;
    cout << "Minimum:" << mini << endl;

return 0;
}
```